# Setting ParameterDirection to ReturnValue for functions

Tags: sql, sql-server, ado.net

The [MSDN documentation on ADO.NET commands and parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy6y35y8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) states:

> ReturnValue: The parameter represents a return value from an operation such as a stored procedure, **built-in function**, or **user-defined function**.

Can this be done in SQL Server? Or any RDBMS?

I tried setting the CommandText to the name of a function:

```cs
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) {
    conn.Open();
    var cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "RAND";

    var parameter = new SqlParameter();
    parameter.Direction=ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(parameter);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    Console.WriteLine(
        "Random number from SQL Server: {0}",
        parameter.Value
    );
}
```

and received the following SqlException:

> Could not find stored procedure 'RAND'.

Comment: Do you have a stored procedure named RAND?

Comment: Try `cmd.CommandText = "RETURN (SELECT RAND())";`

Comment: @RBarryYoung: RAND is a built-in function, not a stored procedure (at least in my case). I was wondering if it could be used by itself, as the MSDN documentation seems to indicate.

Comment: Generally, functions and procedures cannot be used interchangeably in SQL. Can you point to the doc that indicates that so that I can try to see what they meant?

Comment: @Dems: I get `A RETURN statement with a return value cannot be used in this context.`, which I assume means `RETURN` can't be used in a simple SQL statement. (If I try setting `CommandType` to `StoredProcedure` it tries to find a stored procedure named `RETURN (SELECT RAND())`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, you cannot call the "syntactical" builtin functions like that, because they are not real sql objects, and do not show up in any of the object lists (they are implemented syntactically by the compiler).

Other functions can be called like that, but it is not advised both because this is an archaic use, and because it is treating them like procedures and procedures can only have a single `integer` return value.  So if your function is returning a non-integer, it will likely become garbled into something unrecognizable.

Comment: So what is meant by _"The parameter represents a return value from an operation such as a stored procedure, **built-in function**, or user-defined function."_?

Comment: I assume that they were grouping the "system" functions in with the "built-in" functions, even though technically they are two different things.  However, the system funtions could be used like that, but the actual built-in functions are syntactical, they are resolved and implemented by the compiler and the compiler won't recognize them if you try to use them like a procedure.